# Why does the time got by Ubuntu have seconds jumping?

Tags: 16.04, vmware, c++, time

**Background:**
I want to use the system functions to get the UTC to add a time stamp. The function s `getdayoftime()` can help to get the epoch time (beginning as 1970-1-1) and another function `localtime_r` can help to change the epoch time to UTC. I write a simple program to test the stability of time getting. But the results appear the seconds jumping.

**Enviroment:**
Ubuntu 16.04 installed in Vmware Workstation 15.1 in Win 10 (1903).
The program is running in the C++.

**Problem:**
I use matlab to analyze the time differences and the result is below:

[image]

**Codes:**
The code is very easy.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int cnt=0;

    ofstream fp("time.txt");
    
    //For getting the UTC
    struct timeval epochTime;
    struct tm timenow;

    while(1)
    {
        //Get the UTC
        gettimeofday(&epochTime, NULL); 
        localtime_r(&epochTime.tv_sec, &timenow);
        
        //Write time to txt
        fp<<cnt<<","<<timenow.tm_year + 1900<<"-"<<timenow.tm_mon + 1<<"-"<<timenow.tm_mday<<
            " "<<timenow.tm_hour<<":"<<timenow.tm_min<<":"<<timenow.tm_sec<<"."<<epochTime.tv_usec<<endl;

        //sleep for test
        usleep(10000);
 
        if(cnt > 1000)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        cout << cnt << endl;
        cnt +=1;

    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please add your raw data to your question. For your setup, it is not surprising to have some gaps in user response. On my, very idle, bare metal test system I rarely see a gap of even a few milliseconds in user space, however if i do something, such as compile the kernel I get gaps of up to 14 milliseconds, but nothing like what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your commit. I am not sure whether I can upload the raw data (just like the figure or some pictures to show them). I will try it again@DougSmythies